# gcc compile multiple files

Tags: c, gcc

I have these five source

> main.c
>  src_print1.c
>  src_print2.c
>  header_print1.h
>  header_print2.h

the contents are simple and are as following for respective files:

**main.c**

```
#include "header_print1.h"
#include "header_print2.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    print1();
    print2();
    return 0;
}
```

**header_print1.h**

```
#ifndef PRINT_1
#define PRINT_1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print1();

#endif
```

**header_print2.h**

```
#ifndef PRINT_2
#define PRINT_2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print2();

#endif
```

**src_print1.c**

```
#include "header_print1.h"

void print1() {
   printf("Hello 1\n");
}
```

**src_print2.c**

```
#include "header_print2.h"

void print2() {
   printf("Hello 2\n");
}
```

Using `gcc` I have tried to compile using the following command line:

```
  gcc -I ./ -o test -c main.c src_print1.c src_print2.c
```

Everything is in the same folder.
The error I get is:

```
gcc: cannot specify -o with -c or -S with multiple files
```

I looked up at gcc manual, but actually I don't understand what to do in this case, since usually I use IDE and not the command line.

Comment: You should learn how to use `make`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IMHO, if you rewrite your compilation statement like

```
 gcc -I./ -o test main.c src_print1.c src_print2.c
```

You'll be good to go. There is no need for `-c` flag <sup>[NOTE]</sup> when you're specifying the *output* **binary** using `-o`.

Also, as mentioned here, all the files are in same directory, you can even shorten the statement as

```
 gcc -o test main.c src_print1.c src_print2.c
```

**Suggestion:** While the above change(s) will *do the job*, this is not considered an *elegant* way of doing so. Please consider creating a [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) which will make your life easier.

---

[Note]:

Regarding the `-c` option, as per the [online gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options), (emphasis mine)

> -c
>   Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link. The linking stage simply is not done. The ultimate output is in the form of **an object file for each source file**.

So, it should be clear by now, why you got the error.

Comment: What's the difference with the "-c" option?

Comment: @Lukkio: that's exactly the question you should've been asking yourself when including the `-c` option :D It stops the linker from being run, so doesn't make sense with an object file as output.

Comment: I also think gcc will not see any specified `-I` option (or remove them from its buffer?) if they do not appear *at the end*. I don't know which version does that though

Comment: @pmg yeah, just noticed the scenario in this case. Updated.

Comment: @Bastien Useful info, indeed. Integrated that into my answer itself as a suggestion.

Comment: Does it assemble but no links the input files? cannot the compiler assemble multiple files without linking? What's the technical issue in that sense?

Comment: @Lukkio Updated my answer to address your query. Please have a look.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh so basically if i remove the option -o it will return me an object file for each source? Instead using the -o option with a single output file specified the compiler cannot do the job isn't? is this the issue?

Comment: @Lukkio ***NO***. read more in the page i've linked. `-o` is to place the output in a file, irrespective of the type of output. `-c` is to ask compiler to stop after compilation and before linking. These two are different,.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh ..I'm still confused sorry, the page you linked says for the -c option "The ultimate output is in the form of an object file for each source file." while for the -o option says "Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced", i understood that the -c option stop the compilation at the assemble stage, but it gives some output anyway, and i don't get what is the problem there. Probably it is very trivial... but i want to make sure i understand

Comment: @Lukkio You're very right to ask, actually I'm glad you asked. Let me explain in detail. Shall we go to [chat] for further discussion?

Comment: @Lukkio Please join me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79942/gcc-compile-multiple-files).

Comment: My reputation doesn't allow me to chat maybe xD

Comment: @Lukkio I think now you can, pleas re-check.

Comment: I have some problem with the chat... could you try to invite me again, please? It still says "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79943/discussion-between-sourav-ghosh-and-lukkio).