# If I have a directory of cpp files how can I include them all?

Tags: c++

So I'm creating a project with this kind of structure:

```
ProjectFolder
    -SubFolder
        -File1.cpp
        -File2.cpp
        -File3.cpp
        -File4.cpp
    -Header.h
    -Header.cpp
    -main.cpp
```

Is there any way that in `main.cpp` I can `#include "SubFolder"`, such that `File1.cpp`, `File2.cpp`, `File3.cpp`, and `File4.cpp` are all included, without having to write a `#include` for every file (in case the name changes or I add another file to `SubFolder` later?

Yes, including all of them is necessary, as `main.cpp` gets user input to choose which file to run

Comment: You can always `#include /your/path/to/folder/` . But you should really really not include `.cpp` files that's what headers are for :)

Comment: You can concatenate them into single file in Your `Makefile`. But as noted before, You shouldn't need to include cpp into cpp. That's what linker is for.

Comment: You use some kind of tool to build the source files separately into object files, and then possibly create a (static) library to be used when you **link** the application. `make` and makefiles are the classic command-line tool, but it's more common to use tools that create the build files or project files for IDE's (like for example CMake which is quite popular). Or instead of command-line tools use an IDE which will mostly handle it for you.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this. [gcc compile multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30705486/10951000). Naturally, your compiler would be g++.

Comment: So far my CMakeLists ```add_executable``` is like so: ```add_executable(ProjectFolder Header.cpp Header.h main.cpp SubFolder)```, but in ```main.cpp``` I can't ```#include Games```

Comment: (Games here is the name of SubFolder)

Comment: The target name in the CMake [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) command should be the name of the executable program. And the source list must be the actual source files themselves and not directories.

Comment: My solution would be `set(MY_SOURCES "SubFolder/File1.cpp" "SubFolder/File1.cpp")` (add all manually), then `add_executable(main main.cpp ${MY_SOURCES})`. Provide cpp files, headers will automatically be included. (see `include_directories`) If you do not want to write all sources manually, you can use GLOB but it is not recommended.

Comment: So now what do I ```#include``` in main? Do I do each file name? Or do I do MY_SOURCES?

Comment: You `#include` ***header*** files. Files ending in `.h`.

Comment: Yes but which header files? Assuming I've ```set MY_SOURCES``` doing the method @Burak suggested, what am I then doing for ```#include```? I don't want to have to ```#include``` each header file because if I add 100 files to SubFolder, that's going to be a lot of effort and time, and if I add more files later on, that's going to add even more time later down the line.

Comment: You include the ones that you need. The ones that contain the declarations and definitions needed by the current source file.

Comment: I need all of them, as the main file includes them all, then asks the user which file they want to run

Comment: This is turning too much into a very different problem than what you originally asked about, and it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I recommend you take some time to think about the original problem you need to solve, about your own solution, and how to formulate into a *new* question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238650/discussion-between-helpme-and-some-programmer-dude).